# R Shiny - how can I change the color of all sliderInputs created in a loop?

Tags: r, shiny

In a Shiny App, I want to create multiple `sliderInputs` in a certain color, e.g. orange. Since there are *many* sliders as well as `conditionalPanels` depending on the answers to my `sliderInputs`, I'm using a for loop and `renderUI`.

Before I explain a lot of details, please have a look at the code below. I use `semantic.dashboard` for the layout but the important parts happen in the `uiOutput("ratings")` and in the *server function*.

**What I want is all sliders to be in a certain color** (here: orange). I tried different approaches already but so far, I only got the first slider to change its color. I can't get it working together with the loop somehow...

I'm not very familiar with shiny yet. Any help would be highly appreciated, thanks.

```
library("shiny")
library("semantic.dashboard")

color = "orange"
ratings <- c(1:50)

# 1. UI ----
## 1.1 Sidebar ----

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  side = "left",
  color = color,
  sidebarMenu(
    menuItem("Ratings", tabName = "ratings"),
    menuItem("Results", tabName = "results")
    )
)

## 1.2 Body ----
body <- dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName = "ratings",
            fluidRow(
              box(
                title = "Ratings", color = color, width = 16,
                h1("Ratings"),
                p("Please rate."),
                tabPanel("Ratings", uiOutput("ratings"))
              )
            )
        ),
    
      tabItem(tabName = "results",
            fluidRow(
              box(
                title = "Results", color = color, width = 16,
                h1("Results"),
                p("Results will go here.")
              )
            )
      )
    )
)
      
## 1.3 Defining UI ----

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(
    h1("Some Ratings", style = "color:black", align = "center"),
    color = color,
    disable = FALSE
  ),
  sidebar,
  body
)

# 2. Server ----

server <- function(input, output) {

  values <- list()
  for (i in ratings){
   values[[i]] <- box(
     title = paste0("Rating ", i),
     sliderInput(paste0("rating_", i),
                 paste0("Rating ", i),
                 min = 1,
                 max = 7,
                 value = 1,
                 width = "50%"),
     conditionalPanel(condition = paste0("input.rating_", i, " >= 5"),
                      sliderInput(paste0("second_rating_", i),
                                  paste0("Second Rating ", i),
                                  min = 1,
                                  max = 3,
                                  value = 1,
                                  width = "18%"))
                 )
  }
  output$ratings <- renderUI(values)
}

# 3. Run App ----
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define `color` using `setSliderColor()` for appropriate number of `sliderInputs` as shown below

```
  n <- length(ratings)
  values <- list()
  for (i in ratings){
   
    values[[i]] <- box(
      title = paste0("Rating ", i),
      setSliderColor(rep(color,(2*n)), c(1:(n*2))),  ## you can define the color here or on the ui side
      sliderInput(paste0("rating_", i),
                  paste0("Rating ", i),
                  min = 1,
                  max = 7,
                  value = 3,
                  width = "50%"),
      conditionalPanel(condition = paste0("input.rating_", i, " >= 5"),
                       sliderInput(paste0("second_rating_", i),
                                   paste0("Second Rating ", i),
                                   min = 1,
                                   max = 3,
                                   value = 1,
                                   width = "18%"))
    )
  }
```

Comment: great, thanks a lot!! That was easy :) had to install the shinyWidgets package first, but now it looks as it should